# Thread safe Observer design pattern

Tags: c++

Given this code implementing the observer design pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Subject {
    // 1. "independent" functionality
    vector < class Observer * > views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    int value;
  public:
    void attach(Observer *obs) {
        // Lock here *
        views.push_back(obs);
    }
    void setVal(int val) {
        value = val;
        notify();
    }
    int getVal() {
        return value;
    }
    void notify();
};

class Observer {
    // 2. "dependent" functionality
    Subject *model;
    int denom;
  public:
    Observer(Subject *mod, int div) {
        model = mod;
        denom = div;
        // 4. Observers register themselves with the Subject
        model->attach(this);
    }
    virtual void update() = 0;
  protected:
    Subject *getSubject() {
        return model;
    }
    int getDivisor() {
        return denom;
    }
};

void Subject::notify() {
  // 5. Publisher broadcasts
  // Lock here *
  for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}

class DivObserver: public Observer {
  public:
    DivObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
    void update() {
        // 6. "Pull" information of interest
        // What if we have a lock here *
        int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
        cout << v << " div " << d << " is " << v / d << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
  Subject subj;
  DivObserver divObs1(&subj, 4); // 7. Client configures the number and
  DivObserver divObs2(&subj, 3);
  subj.setVal(14);
}
```

I want to make it thread safe, but adding a mutex inside notify may cause a deadlock issue if the client is using two different mutex before adding observer and receiving the notification.

Rule : Never call a callback while locking a mutex.

Is there a solution for that ?

Comment: Do you really need two mutexes? Exactly which processes need to be thread safe?

Comment: No, it's inside a library, the client can use two different mutex before adding an observer or being notified

Comment: In `notify`, copy `views` to a local variable under lock, then run over that copy and call `update` outside the lock.

Comment: Isn't expensive to copy an entire vector for every update ?